# apache2 not loading a php script with form upload, but can load php file without form upload

Tags: php, upload, apache2

i put this code at /var/www/html as index.php and i chmod 777 to this file

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{
    $img = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['img']['name'];
    $img_loc = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="uploads/";
    if(move_uploaded_file($img_loc,$folder.$img))
    {
        echo "<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-wp-preserve="%3Cscript%3Ealert('Upload%20Sukses!!!')%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E" data-mce-resize="false" data-mce-placeholder="1" class="mce-object" width="20" height="20" alt="<script>" title="<script>" />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-wp-preserve="%3Cscript%3Ealert('Upload%20Gagal')%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E" data-mce-resize="false" data-mce-placeholder="1" class="mce-object" width="20" height="20" alt="<script>" title="<script>" />";
    } 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload file dengan PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<br />
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

it shows blank screen, but if i run this php code

```
    <?php
     echo "test"
     ?>
```

it run perfectly

Comment: Have you tried placing the PHP code under the <body> tag?

Comment: You have to set permission to that directory where you want to store the file.